# Warning: Scaling data with a low number of groups may produce misleading results

Tags: r, seurat, dot-plot

When I reduce the number of identity in DotPlot the script return the following warning: "Warning: Scaling data with a low number of groups may produce misleading results"

I use this command:

```
DotPlot(object, features = gene_list, idents=cl, scale = TRUE)
```

Unsuccessfully, I tried to solve the problem following this tutorial: https://satijalab.org/seurat/reference/dotplot

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What is the problem? You just got a warning.

Comment: I want to reduce the misleading results.

Comment: Ok, then show some misleading results that you want to reduce. If you just want an explanation, then this is the wrong venue. Maybe CrossValidated.com?